# NOT EXISTS SQL query in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an sql query like this:-

```
SELECT * FROM `permissions` join entities where NOT EXISTS (select
 entity_id,permission_id from role_permissions where role_id=5 and 
 entities.id = role_permissions.entity_id and permissions.id = 
 role_permissions.permission_id)
```

I would like to get the corresponding rails query.

I have tried this.

```
Permission.joins("join entities").joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN role_permissions on 
 permission_id != permissions.id  and entities.id != entity_id and 
 role_permissions.role_id= role_id").select("role_permissions.entity_id,role_permissions.role_id,
 role_permissions.permission_id").group('role_permissions.entity_id,
 role_permissions.permission_id')
```

But it doesn't works.

thanks
hari

Comment: Would be easier if you described what you want to do in terms of Rails objects. It's almost always futile talking about SQL in a Rails context.

Answer (score 1):

I have been particularly in love with EXISTS queries lately, precisely because it does not require you to fully join another table.  As far as I know, you do have to explicitly write the SQL clause, but you can still make it work with Activerecord.  You can even put this in a scope within a lambda block.

```
Permission.joins(:entities).where(<<-SQL
  NOT EXISTS(
    select
      * from role_permissions where role_id=#{your_role_id} and 
      entities.id = role_permissions.entity_id 
      and permissions.id = role_permissions.permission_id
  )
  SQL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
**UPDATED BASED ON FIRST COMMENT**

```
Permission.joins(:entities).joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN role_permissions on 
  permission_id != permissions.id  and entities.id != entity_id and 
  role_permissions.role_id= role_id")
  .select("role_permissions.entity_id,role_permissions.role_id,
   role_permissions.permission_id")
  .group('role_permissions.entity_id, role_permissions.permission_id')
```

Comment: Sorry it is not working.
We have to join two table namely permission and entities. The result should be combine with NOT Exits of RolePermission table.

Comment: My apologies, dunno why I removed the entities bit :p
Give that a go, can't test it, but i think it may work this time round.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this for a default SQL query:

```
sql = "SELECT some_field FROM `permissions` join entities where NOT EXISTS (select entity_id,permission_id from role_permissions where role_id=5 and entities.id = role_permissions.entity_id and permissions.id = role_permissions.permission_id)"
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
results.each do |result|
    @register_users << { some_field: result[0] }
end
```